# RedisMessageListenerContainer throws ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using the spring data redis 2.1.0 RC2 and my application is throwing the following exception:

> ERROR 394235 [Thread 209] org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer - SubscriptionTask aborted with exception:
>   org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Unknown redis exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast io.lettuce.core.masterslave.StatefulRedisMasterSlaveConnectionImpl to io.lettuce.core.pubsub.StatefulRedisPubSubConnection
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.getFallback(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:53)
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:43)
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceConnection.java:268)
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.pSubscribe(LettuceConnection.java:806)
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer$SubscriptionTask.eventuallyPerformSubscription(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:785)
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer$SubscriptionTask.run(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:752)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast io.lettuce.core.masterslave.StatefulRedisMasterSlaveConnectionImpl to io.lettuce.core.pubsub.StatefulRedisPubSubConnection
>       at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StaticMasterSlaveConnectionProvider.getConnection(StaticMasterSlaveConnectionProvider.java:76)
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.switchToPubSub(LettuceConnection.java:868)
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.initSubscription(LettuceConnection.java:872)
>       at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.pSubscribe(LettuceConnection.java:803)
>       ... 3 more

The exception is caused even after trying different combinations and seems to be originating from the inner classes. Please let me know if this is an issue which needs to be fixed by spring or from my end. Also please let me know if you need more details. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that's throwing this?